# Extract text between brackets and create rows for each bit of text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a pandas dataframe I need to extract text between square brackets and output that text as a new column. I need to do this at the "StudyID" level and create new rows for each bit of text extracted.

Here is a simplified example dataframe

```
data = {
    "studyid":['101', 
                '101', 
                '102', 
                '103'],
    "Question":["Q1",
                "Q2",
                "Q1",
                "Q3"],
    "text":['I love [Bananas] and also [oranges], and [figs]',
            'Yesterday I ate [Apples]',
            '[Grapes] are my favorite fruit',
            '[Mandarins] taste like [oranges] to me'],
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I worked out a solution (see code below, if you run this it shows the wanted output), however it is very long with many steps. I am wanting to know if there is a much shorter way of doing this.

You will see that I used str.findall() for the regex, but I originally tried str.extractall() which outputs the extracted text to a dataframe, but I didn't know how to output the extracted text with the "studyid" and "question" columns included in the dataframe generated by extractall(). So I resorted to using the str.findall().

Here is my code ('I know it is clunky') - how can I reduce the number of steps? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
 # Step 1: Use Regex to pull out the text between the square brackets
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2['text'].str.findall(r"(?<=\[)([^]]+)(?=\])").tolist())

  # Step 2: Merge the extracted text back with the original data
df3 = df2.merge(df3, left_index=True, right_index=True)

  # Step 3: Transpose the wide file to a long file (e.g. panel)
df4 = pd.melt(df3, id_vars=['studyid', 'Question'], value_vars=[0, 1, 2])

  # Step 4: Delete rows with None in the value column
indexNames = df4[df4['value'].isnull()].index
df4.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)

  # Step 5: Sort the data by the StudyID and Question
df4.sort_values(by=['studyid', 'Question'], inplace=True)

  # Step 6: Drop unwanted columns
df4.drop(['variable'], axis=1, inplace=True)

  # Step 7: Reset the index and drop the old index
df4.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If assign back output of [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to column is possible use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), last for unique index is used [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df2['text'] = df2['text'].str.findall(r"(?<=\[)([^]]+)(?=\])")

df4 = df2.explode('text').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Solution with [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), removed second level of `MultiIndex` and last use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for append to original:

```
s = (df2.pop('text').str.extractall(r"(?<=\[)([^]]+)(?=\])")[0]
                   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                   .rename('text'))

df4 = df2.join(s).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print (df4)
  studyid Question       text
0     101       Q1    Bananas
1     101       Q1    oranges
2     101       Q1       figs
3     101       Q2     Apples
4     102       Q1     Grapes
5     103       Q3  Mandarins
6     103       Q3    oranges
```

Comment: Thank you very much jezrael, this is great! The str.extractall() solution is just what I was looking for when I was first working on this. I knew there would be a simple solution to this!

Answer (score 1):

You can "squeeze" your code to a **single** instruction:

```
df2[['studyid', 'Question']].join(df2['text'].str.findall(
    r'\[([^]]+)\]').explode().rename('value'))
```

Even the regex can be simplified: No need for lookbehind / lookforward.
Just place both brackets before / after the capturing group.

If you need, save this result under a variable (e.g. *df4 = ...*).

Note: In your solution you named the last column in the final result (*df4*)
as *value*, so I repeated it in my solution.
But in you want to change this name to whatever you wish, replace *'value'*
in my solution with another name of your choice.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Valdi_Bo for another great solution!